# Why can't i place an image on canvas in paper.js?

Tags: javascript

I have such a piece of code fired when I click on canvas (vue3, paper.js):

```
if (store.selectedTool === 'image' && imageToPlace.value) {
  const image = new store.paperScope.Raster(imageToPlace.value)
  const canvasPosition = store.paperScope.view.viewToProject(event.point)
  image.position = canvasPosition
  store.paperScope.project.activeLayer.addChild(image)
}
```

I would expect that this code would place the image from imageToPlace.value variable on canvas. But it doesn't. Nothing happens, no error. I tried to console.log everything in the code and it seems fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the picture doesn't have time to load and so doesn't appear. you can try to run a loader

```
const image = new store.paperScope.Raster(imageToPlace.value)
    image.onLoad = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        const canvasPosition = store.paperScope.view.viewToProject(event.point)
        image.position = canvasPosition
        store.paperScope.project.activeLayer.addChild(image)
      }, 100)
    }
```